# Calculating loss in dcgan

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to understand [Google's colab code](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r2/tutorials/generative/dcgan.ipynb). Could you clarify why do they compare `real_output` with an array of 1s and `fake_output` with an array of 0s (plain black)?

```
def discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output):
    real_loss = cross_entropy(tf.ones_like(real_output), real_output)
    fake_loss = cross_entropy(tf.zeros_like(fake_output), fake_output)
    total_loss = real_loss + fake_loss
    return total_loss

def generator_loss(fake_output):
    return cross_entropy(tf.ones_like(fake_output), fake_output)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a recap, in a GAN you have a generator which produces an image. The discriminator is another network which tries to predict whether any particular image came from the generator. We'll label images created by the generator (a.k.a. "fakes") as `0`, and we'll label real images as `1`. The discriminators output is in the range `[0, 1]`.

> The arrays of 0's and 1's you see are just the labels assigned to generated or real images.

You should notice that the generator is only trained on the "fake" images, the generator can't train on the real images because it didn't produce them. You should also notice that the generator has swapped the labels from the discriminator, it's trying to achieve the opposite objective than the discriminator is.